# Template docx document quarto

Tags: terminal, rstudio, quarto, powershell-core

I'm new to Quarto and I'm trying to set my template docx document.
I type in the terminal of RStudio :

```bash
quarto pandoc -o custom-reference-doc.docx --print-default-data-file reference.docx
```

but a I get the following error :

> quarto: The term 'quarto' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Any idea where this issue comes from?

I'm using `RStudio 2023.06.1+524 "Mountain Hydrangea"`.

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

I believe someone has already helped you in the [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/template-docx-document-quarto/171136).

However, for anyone else having a similar issue.

**Try:**

- Substituting `quarto` with `quarto.cmd` or `quarto.exe`
- Make sure you installed [Quarto CLI](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/) (not just the R package) by running `quarto check` in **Terminal**

Comment: I did not completely get my issues solved. The issue is that I'm now able to use quarto commands from the MAC terminal but the commands don't work from the R terminal and I get the following errore messages :  /usr/local/bin/quarto: line 7: dirname: command not found
/usr/local/bin/quarto: line 8: readlink: command not found
/usr/local/bin/quarto: line 9: basename: command not found
/usr/local/bin/quarto: line 12: dirname: command not found

ERROR: Cannot determine the Quarto source path. This script must be run from the bin or common folder.

Comment: @PaoloTolomeo Try changing the 'Terminal' settings in RStudio to make sure you are using the same shell as your Mac Terminal (i.e., probably either Zsh or Bash).